# Call a "Event" in Typescript

Tags: jquery, typescript, jquery-file-upload

How can i call the methods `FileUploadProgessAll` and `Done`? The Debugger breaks if i set a breakpoint in the Lampda Method of the `fileuploadprogressall` event/call.

```
export class Upload extends Page
        {
        private FileUpload: JQuery;

        PageLoad(): void
        {
            this.FileUpload = $("#fileupload");
            this.FileUpload.fileupload({
                maxFileSize: 1000000000,
                dataType: "json",
                url: "/Upload/UploadImage",
                autoUpload: true,
                done: this.Done
            }).on("fileuploadprogressall", (event, data) => { return () => this.FileUploadProgressAll(event, data) });
        }

        FileUploadProgressAll(e: JQueryEventObject, data)
        {
        }

        Done(e: JQueryEventObject, data)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can do it easier: `.on("fileuploadprogressall", FileUploadProgressAll)`

If you want the keep the same style: 
`.on("fileuploadprogressall", (event, data) => { this.FileUploadProgressAll(event, data) });`

Comment: @FlorianTopf Sry but both solutions are not working! The first solution can't be compiled because of 'Symbole can not be resolved' and the Second ther is a runtimeerror because of not finding the method 'FileUploadProgressAll'

Comment: sorry forgot: `this.FileUploadProgressAll` with `.this` obviously.

Comment: @FlorianTopf Yes the compile Error is gone, but now nothing happend.

Comment: yes, but your function is doing nothing. :-)

Comment: @FlorianTopf Yes but i set a breakpoint, and now i also tested it with an `alert("Test");`

Comment: `(event, data) => console.log(event, data)` does this spit out something in the console. If not, the event is not triggered.

Comment: @FlorianTopf Yes this works!